# Compare string to match brand name and remove spelling mistakes

Tags: python, string-comparison, spell-checking, spelling

I have a list of texts that contains brand names (Coca-Cola, Pepsi, 7Up ect.). I wrote a python script that sorts and counts all cells that have the same content (the exact same text, after lowercase all text) and reorders the list by the count of each text, so that the texts that appears the most will be first, because I assume that most people will write the brand name correctly. 
For example if I have the following list:

```
texts = ['Coca-Cola', 'Pepsi', 'Coca-Cola', 'Coca-Cola', 'Pepsi', 'Pespi', 'Pepsi', '7Up', '7up', 'Cola', 'Pepsi']
```

After the first step the list will be:

```
ordered_text = [
   {'text': 'Pepsi', count: 4},
   {'text': 'Coca-Cola', count: 3},
   {'text': '7Up', count: 2},
   {'text': 'Cola', count: 1},
   {'text': 'Pespi', count: 1},
]
```

In the second step, I'm using the [ngram](https://pythonhosted.org/ngram/tutorial.html) package to try and match closer texts to correct for spelling mistakes.
Important note: one of my key requests is to have a solution that is agnostic to the language.

My problem is the NGRAM works really well on long text but performs badly on short text. For example when running:

```
ngram.NGram.compare('Pepsi', 'Pespi')
```

the result will be:

```
0.2727272727272727
```

That is a very low 'score', but as you can see the string is really close and there is only 1 letter that is misplaced.

What can I do in order to improve my relust? Do I need to use a different algorithm? Or maybe specify different parameters for this test? I thought about adding a dictionary that contains all 'new' words that I found, add them, then I can compare each word against it, but then I lose the granularity of the script.

Comment: For typos, would [levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) work?

Comment: Perhaps "low = good"? Anyway, personally I prefer using the Levenshtein distance for spell checking. For example, the LD of "missplaed" vs. "misplaced" is `2`. Dividing by the word length, it's 2/9, which is "pretty close".

Comment: In 'NGRAM' you want the score to be as close to 1, that means that the strings are identical.
I general, do you think that it will be best to run the NGRAM algorithm and if it didn't find any match to try and run the  levenshtein distance or to just use the levenshtein distance in this case?

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious from your question if you want to spell-check the inputs for correctness, or you just want to group them. For example, if your input looks like `['coka-cola', 'coak-cola', 'coca-coca']`, what should your algorithm do?

- Should it group them all as `{'coka-cola': 3}`? Meaning always compare inputs against the first occurrence? In this case, edit distance makes sense, you can easily find many python implementations for this.
- Should it group them on correct spelling, so `{'coka-cola': 3}`? In this case you need a good spell corrector. There are a few options here, you can take a look at the [autocorrect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autocorrect/0.2.0) package, or for a more involved solution, the [NLTK](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk) package. Another option is to use Google. I don't think there's a supported API from Google to spell-correct, so you'll have to do some scraping to get the suggested results when issuing a request to Google.

Comment: The end result of the algorithm should be all texts that are similarly grouped together, in you exmple: `[{'coka-cola': 2}, {''coca-coca': 1}]` because the first and second strings are similar and the third one is less similar. is that make sense?

Comment: It's not clear why you think 'coka-cola' and 'coak-cola' are most similar to each other than to 'coca-coca'. If you use edit distance for example, they will all be a maximum of two edits from each other, which is a very low edit threshold.